# Arduino to send sms one time only when a button is pressed

Tags: wires, gsm

The **LED_UPDATE()** is called in my **loop()** function, I implemented it (tried anyways),
to send sms as shown in the code such that  only one sms is sent , because as the **loop()** keeps calling **LED_UPDATE()**, it's going to keep sending an sms every time (yep you guessed it, very bad for credit :o )

any tips on how I can get around this or what i'm doing wrong in my code would be much appreciated.

**p.s.** nearly left my mobile phone in the code lol

```
void LED_UPDATE(int state) 
{

int count; // initialized to zero, once program runs it automatically enter state ==1 
if (state == 1)
{

    digitalWrite(RED_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GREEN_PIN, HIGH);
    count=0; 
}
else if (state == 2)
{
  count+=1;
  Red_Blink();

  if(count == 1 )
  {
    sms.SendSMS("086XXXXXXX", "PANIC BUTTON PRESSED, Subject needs help!!!");
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to sms.SendSMS(string phoneno,string msg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `count` every time you enter the function.

```
static int count; // initialized to zero, once.
```

Adding the static statement should initialise the variable once and preserve its value between calls.